# How to create a new root folder in SharePoint Online Document Library with Graph API in Python

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am able to create folders in folders below the document library root and upload files everywhere, but i can't quite figure out the POST path to create a new folder in the Drive (Document Library) root.   Everything I find assumes already some default folder.  The POST examples provided in [MS documentation requires a parent item ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children).  I have tried many permutations of the POST syntax.

None of these seem to work:

- 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}'
- 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/'
- 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/children'

This is what I use to create folders below the doc lib root:

```
folder_path = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{parent_item_id}/children'
folder_path_values = folder_path.format(drive_id=driveid, parent_item_id=parentid)
```

Here's the code I use to submit the request that is not working:

```
# Some code to get the access_token and the API permissions we have are Files.ReadWrite.All and Sites.ReadWrite.All

driveid = 'b!qyL8-Uu96Uud....JR4eRG9FpH-Z5'
name = 'Drafts'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}

folder_path = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}'
folder_path_values = folder_path.format(drive_id=driveid)

new_folder = {
   "name": name,
   "folder": {},
   "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace"
}

res = requests.post(folder_path_values, json=new_folder, headers=headers)
```

That gives me a 400 error - i cannot seem to figure out the right syntax for creating a new folder (drive) in the root of a document library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a folder under the root, then you can use PATCH

```
PATCH /drives/id/root:/drafts
{
    "folder": {},
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "fail"
}
```

Code

```
driveid = 'b!qyL8-Uu96Uud....JR4eRG9FpH-Z5'
name = 'Drafts'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}

folder_path = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/'+name
folder_path_values = folder_path.format(drive_id=driveid)

new_folder = {
   "folder": {},
   "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace"
}

res = requests.patch(folder_path_values, json=new_folder, headers=headers)
```

If you want to have another folder on the same level as you root, then it's not possible because drive can have only one top-most folder.

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you.  I looked for hours for that solution.   I ended up with folder_path = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/{folder_name}' but otherwise coded exactly like you suggested and it worked.