# If I want to use the Microsoft Graph API to create a new Document Library inside a site in Sharepoint what query should I use

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I tried to use queries like

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/drives/](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BsiteID%7D/drives/) and I get all the document libraries/drives i have inside that site.

But when I try to do a POST at [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/drives/](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BsiteID%7D/drives/) with request Body{
"name": "folderName",
"folder": {
"childCount": 0
},
"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
} . I use this requestBody when i want to create a folder inside a drive with query [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/drives/{driveId}/root/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BsiteID%7D/drives/%7BdriveId%7D/root/children) and it works perfectly

i get Bad Request - 400

Comment: According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74299014/10263175, to create a folder in a library, you must use a PATCH verb, and not POST. Can you try again?